# Deploy/Publish ASP.NET webservice in non IIS environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, deployment

I need to know is there a way to publish ASP.NET webservice application in non IIS environment.

Here is the brief summary:

- I created a ASP.NET webservice application.
- I need to publish this in IIS and non IIS environment
- Publishing in IIS environment is successfully completed
- Publishing in non IIS environment - Not known.

I searched in many places and every where i find deployment process in IIS environment.
Can any one help me if ASP.NET webservice can be deployed / published in non IIS environment.
If yes, how ?

Comment: what do you mean by non-IIs environment? what server you want to deploy it on? be specific

Comment: Manish - Still not sure which server we will be deploying this.But i need to know is there a possibility to publish the asp.net webservice in non IIS environment / publish as a stand alone

Comment: ASP.NET applications are typically run on IIS, so please clarify what do you mean by non-IIS environment.

Comment: alexanderb - I wanted to know can the ASP.NET webservice be deployed / published with out the help of IIS

Answer (score 1):

It seem you are looking for Mono and Mod_Mono for Apache:

"Mod_Mono is an Apache 2.0/2.2/2.4.3 module that provides ASP.NET support for the web's favorite server, Apache.
The module passes off requests for ASP.NET pages to an external program, mod-mono-server, which actually handles the requests. The communication between the Apache module and mod-mono-server is established using a Unix socket or a TCP socket."

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Comment: Hi Oscar , Reading the above link. Thanks